# How to replace variable in string in react

Tags: javascript

I have string

```
const message = "component=\"${component.name}\" and id=${id}";
```

I have data

```
const data = {"id": 101, "component": { "name": "Shiv" }};
```

How to parse this string message, so that "${component.name}" is replaced by "Shiv" and "id" with 100,

I tried using handlebars.js but it is not compatible with my react setup

Comment: Can you change it to ``const data = {id: 101, component: { name: "Shiv" }}; const message = `component=\"${data.component.name}\" and id=${data.id}`;``? (note the backticks)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [javascript template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)?

If it should be dynamic, you can have a function as follows

```
const renderMessage = (data)=>{
   return `component="${data.component.name}" and id=${data.id}`
}
const data = {"id": 101, "component": { "name": "Shiv" }};

renderMessage(data) 
//output is: 'component="Shiv" and id=101'
```

Should get you going on the correct path anyway

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use regular expression to do that like so:

```
const replacePlaceholders = (message, data) => {
// add your expression to match the required pattern
const regex = /\${(.*?)}/g;

const replacedMessage = message.replace(regex, (match, variableName) => {
  return data[variableName] || match; // Use the value from data or the original placeholder if not found
});

return replacedMessage;
};
```